# How to do a map() with setInterval to simulate linux startup process in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I trying to do an Array.map() with setInterval to render some paragraphs with delay to simulate the startup process of linux, I dont know what is wrong cause my setInterval only render the number 3, can you help me with that? (Sorry for my dangerous english)

I try to do that in a react^16.8.6 (web app)

```
const InitialLoading = (props) => {
    const status = [
        'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error',
        'Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas',
        'Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum',
        'Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit'
    ]    

    return <div>
        {setInterval(() => status.map(e => <p>{e}</p>), 5000)}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to render a line every 5 seconds?

Comment: Exactly, I dont know if this is the best way, but that is what i want, Thanks for reply Joss!

Comment: Do you know the length of the status content when the component mounts or is it actively streaming in from somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means an ideal solution, but your question got me thinking about how to do this using promises. It ended up being quite a fun challenge so I thought I'd share my results with you

```
const InitialLoading = () => {
  const initialStatus = [
    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error",
    "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas",
    "Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum",
    "Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit"
  ];

  // Create array of promises that each resolve 1 second apart
  const promises = initialStatus.map((line, index) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(line);
      }, (index + 1) * 1000);
    });
  });

  // Create new empty array where we will add our resolved promises
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create async function that iterates over the promises
    // Once a promise is resolved it gets added to the new array
    // Each time setLines() is called, the DOM is updated with the new array
    const printLines = async () => {
      for (let promise of promises) {
        const line = await promise;
        setLines(lines => [...lines, line]);
      }
    };
    // Call async function
    printLines();
    // Empty array as second argument to force useEffect to only run once
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {lines.map((line, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{line}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit exciting-kepler-ck9wb]

And here is another solution to your problem *without* using promises:

```
const InitialLoading = () => {
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);

  const status = [
    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error",
    "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas",
    "Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum",
    "Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit"
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    status.forEach((line, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLines(lines => [...lines, line]);
      }, (index + 1) * 2000);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {lines.map((line, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{line}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit hungry-firefly-h02iu]

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const initialStatus = [
  "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error",
  "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas",
  "Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum",
  "Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit"
];

function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(initialStatus);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => setStatus(status.concat("new line")), 5000);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {status.map(e => (
        <p key={e}>{e}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit competent-flower-fidlo]

Note: You should be careful about the `setInterval()` and handle it carefully so that it would not flood your application and render too many times.

It'd be helpful if you can share your use case and we can help to suggest a design for you. Perhaps you don't need to use `setInterval()` at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now i know how to prevent a deep loop with  hooks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hooks and `setTimeOut` to do it, this is the code i came up with:

```
const InitialLoading = (props) => {
    const [linesShown, setLinesShown] = useState(0)
    const status = [
        'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error',
        'Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas',
        'Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum',
        'Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit'
    ]    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (linesShown < status.length) {
            setTimeout(() => setLinesShown(linesShown + 1), 1000)
        }
    }, [linesShown]) 

    return <div>
        {status.map((e, index) => (index <= linesShown) ? <p>{e}</p> : null)}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it helped me a lot and I learned a little more about rea: D